# Como configurar o Android Studio para salvar os projetos em uma outra pasta?

Tags: android-studio

Tenho o Android Studio instalado no meu SSD, mas gostaria de configurá-lo para salvar os projetos no meu HD. Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer isso? Procurei em "settings", "other settings" e também tentei achar a resposta na web, mas ainda não consegui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você cria um novo projeto você tem a opção de escolher o lugar que deseja salvá-la.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você consegue mudar também o local que ele busca os últimos projetos:
C:\Users\.AndroidStudio arquivo recentProjects.xml

```
<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="$USER_HOME$/novo_diretório" />
```

Porém, quando for criar o projeto ele ainda irá abrir a opção padrão. Não existe ainda uma maneira de alterar o workspace padrão do Android Studio.